# rails: undefined method for ActiveRecord_Relation with Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have a model named RequestForm that I want to render the seed data in my sample web interface.

The structure of this model looks like this:

table:

```
create_table "request_forms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.date "request_date"
    t.string "submit_by"
    t.string "submit_to"
    t.string "requester_name"
end
```

Seed Data:

```
RequestForm.delete_all

RequestForm.create! (
  [
    {
      requester_name: "David",
      request_date: Date.new(2017,1,2)
    },
    {
      requester_name: "Mike",
      request_date: Date.new(2018,1,3)
    },
    {
      requester_name: "Jack",
      request_date: Date.new(2018,1,3)
    }
  ]
)
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
class Api::RequestFormsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @RequestForm = RequestForm.find(param[:id])
  end

  def index
    @RequestForms = RequestForm.all
  end
end
```

It is resourced in the routes.rb as well

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
      resources :request_forms, only: [ :index, :show ]
end
```

When i tried to create a jbuilder file with a single line:

```
json.extract! @RequestForms, :requester_name, :request_date
```

That's where the 500(internal server error) occur. I clicked into the error message and it said:

```
undefined method `requester_name' for #<RequestForm::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f2c0a879f28>
```

I dont know why it is expecting a relation since from the document in the link here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder:extract!

```
Extracts the mentioned attributes or hash elements from the passed object and turns them into attributes of the JSON.
```

I am simply following the example it provided. So what did i do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `@RequestForms` in your jbuilder template, I'm assuming you're trying to render the index action.

```
json.extract! @RequestForms, :requester_name, :request_date
```

In this case, `@RequestForms` is a `RequestForm::ActiveRecord_Relation`, not a `RequestForm` object. I think what you're looking for is `json.array!` to help you render the collection of objects you have.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
json.array! @RequestForms do |request_form|
  json.requester_name request_form.requester_name
  json.request_date request_form.request_date
end
```

Although, the code you have is pretty close to working. Instead of `json.extract!` you can simply use `json.array!` to extract attributes from the array directly.

```
json.array! @RequestForms, :requester_name, :request_date
```

The [official jbuilder documentation](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) shows this technique like this:

```
# @people = People.all

json.array! @people, :id, :name

# => [ { "id": 1, "name": "David" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Jamie" } ]
```

Comment: so both `json.array! @RequestForms, :requester_name, :request_date` and `json.extract! requestform, :requester_name, :request_date`  works?

Comment: Yes. Both should work. The important point is `json.array!` operates on an array and `json.extract!` operates on an object.

Comment: I see, it was the name convention that was throwing me off. when using `json.extract!`, the object name should be request_forms instead of requestform. The plurality and the snake case convention changed everything. Now it worked. thanks!